# What is a proper way of getting values from a JSON Volley requset?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, inner-classes

I have a JSON request looking like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        url,
        (String) null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                roomArray = parseRoomsResponse(response);
                callback.onSuccess(roomArray);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
}
```

This request is inside the `onCreateView()` method, and my `parseRoomsResponse()` method returns me an `ArrayList` that I wish to work with inside `onCreateView()`, so what is the proper way of doing this thing?

Comment: Yep, looks ok to me. That's how I usually do it.

Comment: I know its ok, i must handle everithing inside onSuccess inner class, is there some way of getting values to onCreateView?

Comment: no. that's what asyncrhonous means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know its ok, i must handle everithing inside onSuccess inner class,
>   is there some way of getting values to onCreateView? –  Zoltan Kurtyak

Ahh.. I see you issue now.

The problem here is that a Request takes an unknown amount of time to return a Response, so Volley makes these requests asynchronously for you rather than lock up your UI thread.
So if you make a Request in `onCreateView`, it's unlikely that you'll still be in `onCreateView` when you get the response.

You may need to rethink the flow of your code. If your fragment's view depends on the Response from a request, then you should probably make sure you do the Request and obtain the Response before you create your Fragment's view.

---

A typical approach to this problem is just use place holder values until the response is received. For example:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    ...
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.response_dependent_edittext);
    myEditText.setText("Loading Data");

    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.response_dependent_imageview);
    myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder);
    ...

    return rootView;
}
```

Then you can create an updateViews method;

```
private void updateViews(ArrayList<MyArrayType> myParsedArray) {

    // Extract relevant data from the array
    ...

    // Replace the place holders in the relevant views
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.response_dependent_edittext);
    myEditText.setText(stringFromParsedArray);

    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.response_dependent_imageview);
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(drawableFromParsedArray);

}
```

and call it from your request's `onResponse` method:

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        myParsedArray = parseResponse(response);
        updateViews(myParsedResponse);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: can i make my program wait for responce before going forward, its ok for me, or i must use onSuccess for this issue?

Comment: Glad it helped you. If the answer solved your problem, remember to mark it as 
Accepted.